# Invalid Opcode Pushing to bytes32[] from transaction

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I have the exact same pattern for addresses and it does fine.

```
bytes32[] public someStorage;

function addToStorage(bytes32 someData) {
  someStorage.push(someData);
}
```

Then using web3:

```
instance.addToStorage("Some Data", {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:1000000})
```

I get a tx address but in testrpc console I see a matching Runtime Error: Invalid Opcode and it always consumes the max gas that I set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a result of truffle not updating the contract artifacts in the build folder.

I've had a couple gotcha's like this and found that compiling with truffle migrate --reset can help